# haystack in a view

Tags: django, django-haystack

Folks. I just can't make the jump from the Haystack tutorial/docs to my (simple) application.

I've got Haystack/Whoosh working per the tutorial, and serving results. Now, instead of a separate search page, I want to search from a form on (say) my archive page and serve the results back into the same page.

I've got this going and showing the search form, and returning the query:

```
def blog_list(request, template_name="blog/blog_list.html"):
    query=request.GET.get('q','')
    form=ModelSearchForm({'q': query })

    extra_context = {
         'query': query,
        'form': form,
    }
    return object_list(
        request,
        queryset=Entry.live.all(),
        extra_context=extra_context
    )
```

But in the template, `{% for result in page.object_list %}` isn't returning anything. Half my problem is that I've no idea where `page.object_list` is coming from and can't fathom it from the tutorial/documentation.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me? Thank you.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I want to create a simple customized search and can't make the jump from the tutorial.  Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't passed in anything called `page`, so naturally it's empty. It doesn't "come from" anywhere, unless you specifically pass it in.

The bit you don't seem to be doing is actually performing the search and passing the results to the template. Look how it's done in Haystack's built-in [`basic_search` view](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/views.py#L193) - it calls the form's `.search()` method, passes the results to the `Paginator` class, and then passes that to the context.

Comment: I suppose I could reply that I'm not specifically passing anything when I set `(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),` yet - there it is. But thanks for the steer - it fell into place as soon as I looked at `basic_search` (and realised what I was looking at).